# MySQL: Limiting n number of duplicates in a column

Tags: mysql, duplicates

A couple of questions as follows:

1. Is there a way to limit the number of duplicates in a particular column? Are there any column properties or settings available?
2. Are there any SQL queries that when run after importing data, remove the duplicates by leaving the first n duplicates of that column intact.

Appreciate your suggestions and guidance on this.

Comment: If `n` is different than `1` the answer to the first question is "no".

Comment: 1) You can stop duplicates, but you cannot allow say 4 duplicates only. 2) YES

Comment: By simulating `row_number() over (partition by columns which make it unique order by something)` using two user variables you could limit the duplicates to n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1:**

Maybe it is not the best solution, but like an option, you can use trigger, like this:

```
create table test (msg varchar(25));

delimiter |
create trigger test_duplicates before insert on test
for each row
begin
  if (select count(*) from test where msg = new.msg) >= 3 then
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'You cannot insert 4th duplicate.';
  end if;
end;
|
delimiter ;
```

And it will work like this:

```
mysql> insert into test values ('this is test');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into test values ('this is test');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> insert into test values ('this is test');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into test values ('this is test');
ERROR 1644 (45000): You cannot insert 4th duplicate.
mysql> select * from test;
+--------------+
| msg          |
+--------------+
| this is test |
| this is test |
| this is test |
+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**2:**

With purpose import data - you can disable trigger on the beginning of import, then import all duplicates, then delete duplicates and then enable trigger, like this:

```
select * from test;
+----------------+
| msg            |
+----------------+
| this is test   |
| this is test   |
| this is test   |
| this is test   |
| this is test 2 |
| this is test 2 |
| this is test 2 |
| this is test 2 |
| this is test 3 |
| this is test 3 |
| this is test 3 |
| this is test 4 |
+----------------+
```

Put duplicates in temporary table:

```
create temporary table tmp like test;
insert into tmp select msg from test group by msg having count(msg) > 3;
select * from tmp;
+----------------+
| msg            |
+----------------+
| this is test   |
| this is test 2 |
+----------------+
```

Now you can see duplicates, can verify for sure, and delete them using data from temporary table.

And now you can enable trigger.

Yes, it is a long way and maybe little bit slow, but it is another option!

Comment: This is really good and working fine, but suppose when i import a large data it is terminating at that condition, rather is there a way to ignore the duplicates and continue the execution of LOAD DATA INFILE 'some.csv'.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your help, however it should retain "this is test" of 3 numbers. :) i will look through it as my requirement is always data gets imported and we need to restrict it every time, Otherwise as you mentioned i need to write a post manipulated action to remove the dupes more than 3.

Comment: OMG))) I've deleted not duplicates but normal data - will improve my example)))

Comment: Thanks, You saved my life. Here is what i did, Just add Id to the temp table as well as test table. So use the Id so that the extra duplicate rows will be removed. I did as follows:                             
                                                                                              
`create temporary table tmp like test;

insert into tmp select id,msg from test group by msg having count(msg) > 4;

select * from tmp;

delete  from test where Id in (select Id from tmp);` When we need to do number of times we need to truncate tmp so that the same Id will not be there

Comment: Yes! You've correctly understood the main idea of my second example!)